# Can't access EC2 hosted website

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

For some reason, I am unable to access our website `www.doccaster.com` (Bad request nginx). We are hosted on amazon EC2 with elastic IP associated to it. The weird part is

1. I can access it through the public dns url http://ec2-184-73-195-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com
2. My co founder who is located in another city can access it via www.doccaster.com.

I observed that my instance was failing reachability check, so I launched a new one and assigned it the the elastic IP. I tried to ping the IP address `184.73.195.180` from my machine but no success. Any help will be really appreciated.

More details I ran the following command on my server

```
netstat -lntp | grep -E 'apache|httpd'
```

and it displays

```
:::80
```

for httpd . Is this accurate ? Should it be `0:0:0:80`? or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have set the wrong IP address in the DNS.

```
error@underground ~ $ host www.doccaster.com
www.doccaster.com has address 199.59.166.86
error@underground ~ $ host doccaster.com
doccaster.com has address 184.73.195.180
```

Once you fix this, you should find things start working.