# Can't access site hosted on EC2 but the public dns url works

Tags: amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t access EC2 hosted website](https://serverfault.com/questions/453498/cant-access-ec2-hosted-website)

For some reason, I am unable to access our website www.doccaster.com (Bad request nginx). We are hosted on amazon EC2 with elastic ip associated to it. The weird part is

a) I can access it through the public dns url http://ec2-184-73-195-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com

b) My co founder who is located in another city can access it via www.doccaster.com.

I observed that my instance was failing reachability check, so I launched a new one and assigned it the the elastic ip. I tried to ping the ip address 184.73.195.180 from my machine but no success. Any help will be really appreciated.

More details I ran the following command on my server

`netstat -lntp | grep -E 'apache|httpd'` and it displays

`:::80` for httpd . Is this accurate ? Should it be 0:0:0:80 ? or doesnt matter?

Comment: offtopic. not a programming problem. try serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also get 400 Bad Request

```
# curl -I "http://www.doccaster.com"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Date: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 16:19:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 166
```

<strike>You probably have an error in your nginx configuration for this specific domain.
Could you please post it for a review?</strike>

I found the reason for both - why you can't and why your co-founder could access the website. You didn't set up www.doccaster.com for the correct IP address, while doccaster.com is.

```
doccaster.com.          1631    IN      A       184.73.195.180  # correct
www.doccaster.com.      1090    IN      A       198.187.31.244  # wrong
```

Your co-founder went to http://doccaster.com/ which is working.

Just fix your DNS settings for the domain

Note, that pinging EC2 instances is not possible by default. 
ICMP requests (ping sends a probe using ICMP protocol) are blocked by the security group

Comment: I am not using nginx at all. I am not sure why the request is being process by nginx . I am using apache.

Comment: also, good luck with this pretty cool idea

Comment: Thanks Michel for all your help , I fixed it some time back and now its working.

Comment: you're welcome.. just hire me when you're bigger than facebook k? ;)